# SQL: How to Count Based on Other Column For Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am a relative novice at SQL and Microsoft Access, and I was wondering if someone could help me solve a problem I've been having.

I have a database full of different parts with different part numbers, and I want to find the unit price at which each part was most frequently purchased. Here is an example of the format my database is in which shows the numerous times the parts have been purchased:

### Part Number | Unit Price |

- 3XG-32Q  |   $0.24    |
- 3XG-32Q  |   $0.26    |
- 3XG-32Q  |   $0.26    |
- E7Y-FG8  |   $0.24    |
- E7Y-FG8  |   $0.38    |
- E7Y-FG8  |   $0.24    |

...and so on.  Here is the code I have used thus far not to find the price at which each part was purchased most frequently, but to try and find how many times each part has been purchased at each price:

```
SELECT Database.PartNumber, Database.UnitPrice, COUNT(Database.UnitPrice) as Number_Of_Orders
FROM Database
GROUP BY Database.PartNumber, Database.UnitPrice
ORDER BY Database.PartNumber;
```

The problem with this that I can't fix is that the amount of occurrences of each price is counted throughout the entire sheet, not specifically within the confines of one part number. This code will will give a value of 3 in the Number_Of_Orders column next to every occurrence of the price $0.24, even though I want that value to be 1 so I can compare it to the amount of times the part 3XG-32Q was purchased for $0.26 and determine that $0.26 is the most-often ordered price for that part.

How can I change my count function, or add other aspects to the code, to only count the number of times each price occurs in the context of a single part?

Answer (score 0):

The count will be per value as grouped by. If not, something else is going on:

```
SELECT 
    Database.PartNumber, 
    Database.UnitPrice, 
    COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Orders
FROM 
    Database
GROUP BY 
    Database.PartNumber, 
    Database.UnitPrice
ORDER BY 
    Database.PartNumber,
    COUNT(*) Desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a pain in MS Access.  You need a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT d.PartNumber, d.UnitPrice, COUNT(d.UnitPrice) as Number_Of_Orders
FROM Database as d
GROUP BY d.PartNumber, d.UnitPrice
HAVING Number_Of_Orders = (SELECT MAX(d3.Number_Of_Orders)
                           FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as Number_Of_Orders
                                 FROM Database as d2
                                 WHERE d2.PartNumber = d.PartNumber
                                 GROUP BY d2.UnitPrice
                                ) as d3
                          )
ORDER BY d.PartNumber;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Gordon. Unfortunately, I have had some problems implementing your code. In order to implement the table aliases correctly, I made a second reference to the table with the "d" alias, as you called it, in the third nested from statement, along with the d2 declaration. That's the only significant change I made, but now when I try to run the code it gives a dialogue box asking for the value of "Number_Of_Orders", and after pressing OK outputs a blank sheet. Is the Number_Of_Orders in the having statement undefined? Do you have a recommendation on how to fix this?